# How to get difference of two pandas indices, but only those of the first index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, time

I got two indices, `Ix1` and `Ix2`.
I need the ones from `Ix1`, that are not in `Ix2`.

I only know

```
Ix1.difference(Ix2).intersection(Ix1)
```

But it doesn't work. I still get indices from `Ix2`, which aren't in `Ix1`. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use first part only:

```
Ix1 = pd.Index([1,2,3,6,7])
Ix2 = pd.Index([0,1,2,4,5])

print (Ix1.difference(Ix2))
Int64Index([3, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: @La-Li-Lu-Le-Lo - be free modify my sample data from answer.